# Django - Update an html table every 1 minute

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to update an HTML table (client side) every minute without refreshing the page in a django project?

If yes, please, just let me know what I should look for in order to achieve this result.

Please, do not down vote my question due no code. I did not start the project yet.

Comment: Since you've specified client side, this would have nothing to do with Django (and especially not with Django models). This would be entirely the job of your front-end (JS) code.

Comment: "Please, do not down vote my question due no code. I did not start the project yet." Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and [ask]. It is very hard to ask questions that aren't too broad if you don't have any code yet. We're not here to write or find tutorials for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into javascript timers if your want to do something every time interval.
For examle `setInterval(myTimer, 1000);` will call the `function myTimer()` every second.

I assume you want to update the table with information from your server.
You can do an AJAX request eiter to get the table html (generate table serverside) and replace it in your document or to get data to put into your table via javascript (generate table clientside).

Comment: thanks for your support. I was able to do it using the combination of setInterval + AJAX request. Later on, I also could implemente it using setInterval + Vue3 + Axios.